# Find duplication in multi tables

Tags: sql-server

We have 4 tables
Student, School, Location and StudentSchool
Students can can have same name but they are different persons
each student can be in one school only and each school located in one location
[image]

We found out that same student is somehow located in 2 different school

[image]

In this example "Adam Mike" with the Id '1' is located in 2 different schools in different locations.

How can i find a list of all students who are located in 2 different school?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to search one table

```
select student_id 
  from school_student 
 group by student_id
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry i made a mistake in my description, i edited my question

Comment: You changed the question and removed the table detail needed to answer it.    Come on.

Comment: Ok as i said i made a mistake i will mark it as answer and i will create a new post. thank you

Comment: You still removed the detail.  If you are going to accept you should roll the question back.  I have the privilege to roll back a question but I don't like doing that.

Comment: How can i do that, this is what i'm trying to do

Comment: OK I will roll it back for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the result, group students by name (`group by` in SQL), producing their count in the group (`count(*)` in SQL), then filter only those who have count > 1 (`having count(*) > 1` in SQL).

I don't know how to express it in the query building tool, but it must support it.

Note that such grouping will lose IDs and school names; you will have to query for them again using the names.