# Identify wrong data

Tags: sql, sql-server

We discovered wrong data in one of our table and we would like to identify them.

We have 4 tables:

- Student
- School
- School_Student
- Location

The relation between them as follow

- Each location has many schools
- Each student can be in different schools in the same location

[image]

Due that some students have the same name although they are different persons with different ID, we found that some students are assigned to different schools in different locations

[image]

You can see in the screenshot that "Adam Mike" is assigned to 3 different schools, the second and the third line are ok because the location of the school is the same however the first line is not ok because the school is in a different location.

so i would like to have a query that returns all students that are assigned to different locations so that i can manually correct them.

Thank you

**EDIT**

In my last question [Find duplication in multi tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934490/find-duplication-in-multi-tables) 
the student cannot be in different school.

To make it more clear.

[image]

In this screenshot you see that all records with "?" are not correct because the location is different.
So mike cannot be in a school in USA and in GB
in the otherhand JIM is in different schools but in the same location so this is ok
Now i would like to find all records where students has records in different locations.

Comment: You have too much rep around here for a question this poor. Where is the ddl? Where is the sample data? What is the desired output? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Maro - I'm unable to see the data in the image link, could you create a small sample of the data in a code block.

Comment: I think what is worse is this is an extension of your previous question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934490/find-duplication-in-multi-tables The fact that you can't modify the answer there for this demonstrates that you don't understand the solution very well.

Comment: If you can see the last screenshot, you will find that "Adam Mike" is assigned to 3 schools, this is ok as long as the school location is the same however one of these schools is located in different location"for example "country" which is not possible

Comment: if you can read the comments in my previows question you will see that i made a mistake and we decdied to create a new one

Comment: I will update m qeustion

Comment: All you need to do is add LocID to the group by.

Comment: I don't think it's that simple, because adding any grouping will return duplication, if you see my last screenshot, grouping by locId whill return both Mike and Jim. i'm only interested in records with different location for the same student.
Any way, i guess i couldn't express my question correctly, thanks any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like. It returns the students that have more than 1 unique location.

```
SELECT ss.student_id
FROM school s
JOIN school_student ss
  ON s.id = ss.school_id
GROUP BY ss.student_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.location_id) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, i will check your answer

Comment: This is what i'm looking for, thank you for your efforts